# Java - Update Elements in Large XML Files

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, stax

I work with very large XML datasets (1 GB+) and need to backtrack and update specific elements per node, depending on the values of other elements that follow.

For example, in this record/node:

```
<user>
    <role>Associate</role>
    <team>Hufflepuff</team>
    <experience>7</experience>
</user>
```

Since "experience" is greater than 5 years, the role needs to be updated from "Associate" to "Senior."

I would like to avoid loading the entire file into memory via the DOM.

Ideally, I would process each single "user" in the XML and append the data to a new XML file one at a time. I started off by processing in a stream using StAX, but I don't know how to transform each XMLEventWriter event content into a useable DOM document that writes to an XML file and clears from memory afterwards.

If the description is unclear in any way, please let me know. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using streaming in XSLT 3.0, you can do

```
<xsl:template match="user" mode="streamed">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of(.)" mode="unstreamed"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and in the unstreamed mode you can then process the (copied) `user` element as a subtree in memory with no streaming restrictions.

I've done the same with SAX; it's easy enough when you hit a startElement event for `user` to start building a tree, and when the corresponding endElement event occurs, to process that tree any way you like.

I wouldn't use a pull API like StAX for this. I'm sure it can be done, but it's probably more effort.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm currently not familiar with using XSLT, although I know it's very popular and will be fine with learning it if it provides the optimal solution in this context. I did want to ask a few questions first.

There will be a lot of intermediate Java processing when elements with specific values are found in a node, before updating a prior element. For example, if "experience" and "team" match a certain value, make a Database call and then process the returned values before replacing the original element.

Do you still think XSLT will be the tool for the job here?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it's a professional approach to make recommendations on application architecture and technology selection based on a one-paragraph statement of requirements. There are too many variables: size of project, skills available, timescales and costs, etc etc. I wouldn't hesitate doing it in XSLT myself, but that doesn't make it the right choice for everyone.

Comment: That's helpful. The main thing I wanted to find out was if XSLT would even allow for intermixing with Java processing, and it sounds like it will. I'll look into this as a potential option. Thanks, Michael.